# How to get only those that satisify date-only part of timestamp, not time

Tags: postgresql

The problem is timestamps are like Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second and my WHERE condition needs to ONLY care for the year-month-day portion.

I have tried conditioning for DATE(). I have tried truncate() and have also just simply tried only `WHERE created_on = '2019-01-01'` and have not have any results show up.

My table columns are:

```
id|event_status|created_on
```

created_on being the timestamp field.

[57014] ERROR: canceling statement due to statement timeout

and no results showing up at all.

Comment: Your error seems nothing to do with the problem "timestamp to date". Maybe your call is on a very huge data set? Are there any restrictions at the database. The statement simply times out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the timestamp to a date:

```
WHERE created_on::date = date '2019-01-01'`
```

However that will not be able to use an index on `created_on` which might be the reason for the timeout.

Another way of writing this that can make use of an index on `created_on` is to use a range condition:

```
WHERE created_on >= date '2019-01-01' 
  and created_on < date '2019-01-02'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a `timestamp` into a `date`. This truncates the `time` part

```
WHERE created_on::date = '2019-01-01'::date
```